# How can I install the Go compiler support for VS Code on fedora 34?

Tags: go, fedora, rpm

Would you tell me how to install Go compiler support for VS Code in fedora 34?

Answer (score 1):

You install first go as per the instructions on the [fedora website](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/go/go-installation.html).

```
sudo dnf install golang
```

After that you can search for the golang extension inside vscode and install that.